# How can I scrape data from this table with Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, data-mining

Unfortunately, I am an absolute beginner in the field of web scraping, but I would like to deal with it intensively in the near future. I want to save the data of a table with a Python script in an Excel file, which is also not a problem. However, the source code of the website does not contain any of the values that I would like to have. When examining, the values are entered in the HTML structure, but when I use the XPath, it is output that this is not permitted, that this is not permitted. If I use the Chrome add-on "DataMiner", it can read out the values. How can I achieve this myself in Python? In the picture, the data I want to scrape is shown. Unfortunately, this data is not included in the source code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://herakles.webuntis.com/WebUntis/monitor?school=Europaschule%20Gym%20Rhauderfehn&monitorType=subst&format=Test%20Sch%C3%BCler'

from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
htmlSource = browser.page_source
print(htmlSource)
```

Update: The script now prints out the source code, but when searching for an element by the XPath, it still doesn't show anything. As I already said, I'm completely new to Python and web-scraping.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olm53.png)

Comment: Please include the updated code from your Update, we cant tell if anything is wrong with your xpath if we dont know what xpath you are using

Answer (score 1):

here's a version with requests only. you can obtain the payload data from your devtools network tab

```
import requests

get_url="https://herakles.webuntis.com/WebUntis/monitor?school=Europaschule%20Gym%20Rhauderfehn&monitorType=subst&format=Test%20Sch%C3%BCler"
post_url="https://herakles.webuntis.com/WebUntis/monitor/substitution/data?school=Europaschule Gym Rhauderfehn"

payload={"formatName":"Test Schüler","schoolName":"Europaschule Gym Rhauderfehn","date":20211204,"dateOffset":0,"strikethrough":True,"mergeBlocks":True,"showOnlyFutureSub":True,"showBreakSupervisions":False,"showTeacher":True,"showClass":True,"showHour":True,"showInfo":True,"showRoom":True,"showSubject":True,"groupBy":1,"hideAbsent":True,"departmentIds":[],"departmentElementType":-1,"hideCancelWithSubstitution":True,"hideCancelCausedByEvent":False,"showTime":False,"showSubstText":True,"showAbsentElements":[],"showAffectedElements":[1],"showUnitTime":True,"showMessages":True,"showStudentgroup":False,"enableSubstitutionFrom":True,"showSubstitutionFrom":1600,"showTeacherOnEvent":False,"showAbsentTeacher":True,"strikethroughAbsentTeacher":True,"activityTypeIds":[2,3],"showEvent":True,"showCancel":True,"showOnlyCancel":False,"showSubstTypeColor":False,"showExamSupervision":False,"showUnheraldedExams":False}

with requests.session() as s:
    r=s.get(get_url)
    s.headers['Content-Type']="application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    r=s.post(post_url,json=payload)
    print(r.json())
```